# Sencha Touch Cross Origin Error

Tags: sencha-touch

I am trying to make ajax request using Sencha Touch 2 but I am getting the *cross origin error*.
I am using `Ext.Ajax.Request` for sending the ajax request with `POST` method.
I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: The framework is irrelevant.  Are you trying to POST to a different site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many question regarding this issue

[Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue with mobile web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332535/access-control-allow-origin-issue-with-mobile-web-app)

[Sencha touch 2 json + twitter = Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752798/sencha-touch-2-json-twitter-access-control-allow-origin)