# MLHttpRequest cannot load in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am designing app where I am facing following error of cross domain in google chrome:
1.XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
2.Origin localhost:8080' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
Please provide step by step way to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha Touch Cross Origin Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908087/sencha-touch-cross-origin-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps shown in figure.[image]

When you build your app to android kindly use cordova. It handle cross domain issue in mobile application. Unless when you try your application on localhost you have to disable your browser security.

If your chrome browser opened kindly close it and follow the steps.

**Right click on your chrome shortcut icon and select properties and type**

> --disable-web-security

and open your browser you will see the warning from browser in yellow ribbon as shown below.

Comment: Yes I have Tried this steps but chrome not giving me that message.What else I need to do?

Comment: i got your problem. I faced that problem.
You need to install another Broswer for that purpose Chromium
** http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Internet/Browsers/X-Chromium.shtml** and do the same procedure explained above. I hope it will resolved your problem.

Comment: please tick this answer ;-)